# Is Network Bridging secure

Tags: security, bridge

Bridging two network cars in Windows allows the two separate networks to connect.

Assuming there are three NIC cards present in a machine: A, B and C. 
If I bridge NIC A and B, is there a possibility for NIC C to have access to the data flow given that all NICs in the same machine?

Would the communication between NIC and B be considered a closed circuit network?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are no security features inherent in bridging or routing.
2. To answer your specific question, it all depends on how you've confiured your Windows system.  As you probably know, there are many vulnerabilities in Windows (also all other OSes). Some could be exploited to compromise your system.

Specific questions about host and OS configuration are off-topic here.  You can try asking for more details on the Information Security SE.